# (7 - 12) mod 24 equals 19 but in C++ it equals 4294967291

Tags: c++, math

If I google `(7 - 12) mod 24` I get the answer `19`.

When I do it C++ I get 4294967291

```
uint32_t hour = (7 - 12) % 24;
// hour = 4294967291
```

If I try an int32_t

```
int32_t hour = (7 - 12) % 24;
// hour = -5
```

Comment: When you convert [singed to unsigned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22801069/using-1-as-a-flag-value-for-unsigned-size-t-types) you add or subtract `UMAX+1` to get a valid unsigned value. For example converting `-1` to unsigned will always give you the max unsigned value for that type.

Comment: In C++, `/` does truncation-towards-zero, so `-5 / 24 == 0`. `%` is defined such that `(a/b)*b + a%b == a`, therefore it must be `-5`.

Comment: Don't mix signed and unsigned values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(7 - 12) % 24` is a signed expression, and assigning it to an `unsigned int` makes you see a different result

In C `%` is the remainder operation so `(7 - 12) % 24 = -5`

```
unsigned(-5) = 4294967291 // since 4294967291 + 5 = 4294967296
```

While Google and Python uses the mathematics modulus operation, the result is 19. And 19 + 5 = 24

[C,Python - different behaviour of the modulo (%) operation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1907565/995714)

Comment: Saying `4294967291 + 5 = 4294967296` does not really explain why, you can see my answer to the question I [linked above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22902364/7-12-mod-24-equals-19-but-in-c-it-equals-4294967291#comment34952458_22902364) for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

7-12 ans an unsigned int (uint32) gives underflow.

See also 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation
for definition of the operator for negative numbers in respect to the programming language

Comment: Makes sense.  Why does the int32_t result not match Google?

Comment: @blindsamuel http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082917/mod-of-negative-number-is-melting-my-brain?rq=1

Comment: The result is not undefined.

Comment: It's definitely defined: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221409/is-unsigned-integer-subtraction-defined-behavior

Comment: If you try to store an out-of-range value in `unsigned int`, it is adjusted modulo `UINT_MAX+1` until it fits

Comment: Updated answer -- undefined was definitely not the right word.

Answer (score 1):

`uint32_t` is unsigned, meaning that it is restricted to positive numbers. It also means it has a larger range, since a signed byte can have values from -127 to 127, but an unsigned byte can have them from 0-255. When the unsigned int underflows, it will return a large number.

The reason that the `int32_t` is returning -5 instead of 19, is because in [C++ and C# the modulus operator is actually remainder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082917/mod-of-negative-number-is-melting-my-brain/6400477#6400477).

Also see [this blog psot](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/12/05/what-s-the-difference-remainder-vs-modulus.aspx) by Eric Lippert that sums this up amazingly. Specifically...

*"The % operator does not give the canonical modulus, it gives the remainder.
"*

Meanwhile, google gives the canonical modulus since `-123 mod 4 = 1`, not `-3`, as it would be in C++ or C#.

Comment: @RobertHarvey So [remainder != modulus](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/12/05/what-s-the-difference-remainder-vs-modulus.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how this addresses the question at all.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Check edits... I just didn't want to beat a dead horse with the whole unsigned/signed thing, but the actual operator still needed to be addressed.

Comment: So far, nobody's provided a decent answer to the question anyway.  I stated simply in my answer that a negative number can't be stuffed into an unsigned int without consequences, but apparently that's not specific enough.  The right answer is to use the correct data type.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The question(s) being asked are not amazingly clear

Comment: That's part of the reason I decided to close it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The only reason I even posted an answer was [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22902364/7-12-mod-24-equals-19-but-in-c-it-equals-4294967291/22902430?noredirect=1#comment34952428_22902375)

Comment: Ah, I see.  Well, it's better to address the question that was asked in the question in an answer, rather than a question that was asked in a comment, a matter best responded to in another comment, not an answer (since, by responding in an answer, nobody knows what the hell is happening).

Answer (score 0):

The modulus operation actually has several different possible definitions producing various results for negative numbers. C++'s definition gives a negative result (-5) for the expression `(7 - 12) % 24`, and when you cast a negative value to an unsigned value you get that strange result. That value is the same as what you get if you were to do:

```
uint32_t x = 0;
x = x - 5;
```