# c - initialize unsigned datatype with -1

Tags: c, unsigned

Is it okay to initialize an `unsigned` datatype with -1 to get it to the highest value?

Or may this cause any problems?

Comment: Yes it is well defined see the likely duplicate: [Using -1 as a flag value for unsigned (size_t) types](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22801069/1708801)

Comment: Well here I am spending more than 10 minutes to search for this topic. And here you are showing this to me in 1 minute. Not saying it is better to post than to search but sometimes the search is very frustrating, because obviously I used the wrong terms. Thank you very much.Your answer there is the answer to mine but the question is different it seems :D

Comment: Well I answered the question I linked to so I already knew the answer, I don't think this is an easy topic to search for.