# Behaviour of Type promotion in C (from lower signed to higher unsigned)

Tags: c, casting, binary

I encountered a bug in a piece of code to convert little endian binary stream into a unsigned int value.

```
u_int64  get_unsigned_int_from_binary_stream (u_int8 *data, u_int32 length)
{
    uint idx;
    u_int64 value = 0;

       if (!length) {
       return 0;
    }

    value = data[0];
    for (idx = 1; idx < length; idx++) {
        value = value | ((data[idx]) << (8 * idx));
    }
    return value;
}
```

It turns out that the culprit was data[idx] type promotion.
Since 8*idx would lead into a signed int and data[idx] is of type uint8 , the whole thing would get promoted into the higher type that is signed int32. And a negative number was messing up the complete value.

My question is why would a type cast of a negative value from int32 to u_int64 lead into all the first 32 bit set to 1 ?

To given a specific example, similar thing can be seen with.
(gdb) p /t (u_int64) (int8)-1
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

Why are all the newly introduced bit in the higher type are set to 1 when the original lower order type had only 1st bit set to 1 to indicate negative sign?

Comment: See [Using -1 as a flag value for unsigned (size_t) types](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22801135/1708801) which explains your -1 example.

Comment: You have undefined behaviour.  I've been caught out by this before.  See the above linked duplicate, where I was incorrectly assuming that the default integer promotions for shifting a character type would select the largest supported integer type.

Comment: Thank you, the comments helped me understand the issue.