# C++ length error exception cannot be catched

Tags: c++, exception

When I use:

```
throw "something happen"
```

__cxa_throw can catch this exception.

But if I write:

```
std::string s; s.resize(-1);
```

__cxa_throw cannot catch it;
I want to know why and how to fix it.

UPDATE: sorry for incomplete description. My purpose is to know the crash stack when

```
std::string s; s.resize(-1);
```

was called.
If it not throw any exception, what should I do?

Sorry，I forgot to attach the picture.
The first page is

```
std::string s; s.resize(-1);
```

The second one is

```
throw "something happen"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nT89V.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DU1CV.png)

Comment: How is `__cxa_throw` involved in *catching* an exception? And could you show some of the code you use to test this?

Comment: what do you mean by "__cxa_throw cannot catch it"? And please post the code you used to catch it.

Comment: What's the connection between the first and the second code example?

Comment: You do not throw in the second example. What do you think happens, when you "shrink" an empty string to -1?

Comment: `resize(-1)` does not do what you think it does. Hint: the parameter to `resize` is `size_t` which is unsigned

Comment: Actually My purpose is to get the crash call stack when the crash happened, and I dont know if there is exception thrown when "s.resize(-1)" and how can I catch it.

Answer (score 2):

The [std::string::resize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize) member function does not raise an exception in your case because the integer literal of `-1` is always converted to the max unsigned value of `std::size_t` type which is what the function accepts and may result in `4294967295` for 32-bit platforms or `18446744073709551615` on 64-bit platforms or similar. The exception that can be thrown is the [std::length_error](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/length_error). This SO post has more information:
[Using -1 as a flag value for unsigned (size_t) types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22801069/using-1-as-a-flag-value-for-unsigned-size-t-types)

Comment: Thanks for answer, I modified the question and hope you can tell me what should I do.

Comment: I'm not so sure if there is any exception been thrown, So I confused why the function __cxa_throw cannot catch it. Actually the system seems not called the function.