# size_t arithmetic with negative value

Tags: c++, string

I was asked to make a copy of `std::string` in an assignment and I am having problem implementing the `substr` function. In a set of tests the teacher gave us there was one with a `length` equal to `-1`. Mine declaration of `substr` is:

```
Cadena substr(size_t start, size_t length) const;
```

Which I (thought) that the `size_t` would prevent negative values to be passed. The problem is that in the definition I check for `size() < start + length` (assume `tam_` is the same as `size()`):

```
    if (tam_ <  start + length)
        throw std::out_of_range("Error");
```

In my system `-1` in `unsigned`  is `18446744073709551615`, so that, for example assume start is `9` and `tam_` is `10`.

I expect:

```
10 <  9 + 18446744073709551615
```

So that the exception is thrown, but in reality I get

```
10 < 9 + (-1)
```

Which is false and exception isn't thrown. As the function continues it allocates a char array for size `length + 1`, which the system refuses due to that `new[]` treats the `size_t` as it should be, `18446744073709551615`, which is so large it makes the program crash.

I want to know why my expected result isn't the correct.

Comment: You may be interested in [`std::string::npos`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos) which does something similar in the standard library. You will likely have to check for the case where `length` is `(size_t)-1` explicitly.

Comment: Using `unsigned` doesn't prevent negative numbers from being passed. They just get converted to a large positive number.

Comment: `unsigned` wrap around.

Comment: `unsigned` types use modular arithmetic.

Comment: Quick demo: https://ideone.com/JMkBod

Comment: [minus 1 will be converted to max unsigned value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22801135/1708801) this is expected behavior.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I forgot to mention that I can't use anything from STL string implementation.

Comment: @Cako But you can use it as a reference as to how it has been done before, which I think was the point.

Comment: @Barmar I didn't know about it. Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't be handling the case where the user passes in a negative value. *I mean how could you even check that?* The fact that the parameter is of type `std::size_t` should be enough to tell someone that negative values are not accepted, and if they choose to, then let them suffer the consequence. On the other hand, I think it's a good test for you because I don't see why you should allocate an array bigger than the initial string you start with, in order to store the sub string. You need to fix your logic, then you wouldn't need to handle the special case of `-1`

Comment: Easiest way to handle this, is to do `length = std::min(length, tam_)`, then continue with the rest of the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overflow and underflow problems are hard to check for.  In general, you need to check before you do the arithmetic, not afterward.

First, let's be clear what's happening.

```
// The call
foo.substr(9, -1);
```

The `-1` is an `int`, but the function takes a `std::size_t` so `-1` is converted, and you get the Really Big Number (RBN).

Then, you test:

```
size() < start + length
```

These are unsigned types, so if the arithmetic (i.e., the addition) exceeds the upper or lower bounds of the range that can be represented, the value will wrap around.  (With signed types, the behavior would be undefined.)

Here, `length` is the RBN.  When you add `start` and the RBN, the addition wraps around to a small number.  You missed detection of the overflow.

To fix it, you need to check two things:  (1) that `start` is within bounds and (2) that the remainder of the string after `start` is longer than `length`.

```
if (start > size() || size() - start < length)
  throw std::::out_of_range("Error");
```

Step (1) is key because it guarantees that the subtraction in Step (2) won't go below 0.